# Jumpy YouTube Live inserted CEA-608 captions

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

We are inserting live video with CEA-608 captions to YouTube Live, and noticed that the same captions that show properly on Twitch, or LinkedIn, jump from center to the left side of the screen. The same behavior was recorded when using the YouTube Live API or creating a live stream in the Creator Studio (with RTMP ingest and a stream key).

The data is inserted with the live video as CEA-608 and the stream is configured as such. We are using the Google Cloud Speech to text API (caption automation) to insert the captions or in a manual mode on our end (human generated captions).

We expect the live video with CEA-608 captions to show in the area the user selects in the closed captioning section of the YouTube player. Again, this works on other platforms but not on YouTube.

Thanks,
Eyal